# How to resolve error "play - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't serialize class" in scala?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am using scala case classes and play framework to process some data.
Here is a my code:

```
case class myClass(
datastores: Option[List[DataStores]])

case class DataStores(
name: Option[String],
utilization: Option[DataStoreUtilization],
luns: Option[List[DataStoreLuns]]
)

case class DataStoreUtilization(
freeBytes: Option[Long],
sizeBytes: Option[Long],
usedBytes: Option[Long])

case class DataStoreLuns(
model: Option[String],
canonicalName: Option[String],
vendor: Option[String])

object myClass extends ModelCompanion[myClass, ObjectId] {

val collection = MongoClient("mongoserver", 27017)("myDB")("myCollection")
val dao = new SalatDAO[myClass, ObjectId](collection = collection) {}

def apply(rawData: JsValue): myClass = {
  val datastoreList = getDataStoreList(rawData)

myClass(datastoreList)
}
private def getDataStoreList(rawData: JsValue): Option[List[DataStores]] = {
val commandInfo = (rawData \ "Commands").as[JsValue]
(commandInfo \ "dataStores").asOpt[List[JsObject]].map { dataStores =>
  dataStores map {
    dataStoreJson =>
      val name = (dataStoreJson \ "name").asOpt[String]
      val utilization = getDataStoreUtilization(dataStoreJson)
      val luns = getDataStoreLuns(dataStoreJson)
      // val virtualMachines = getDataStoreVirtualMachines(dataStoreJson)
      DataStores(name, utilization, luns)
  }
  }
 }

  private def getDataStoreUtilization(dataStoreJson: JsObject): Option[DataStoreUtilization] = {

(dataStoreJson \ "utilization").asOpt[JsObject].map {
  case utilizationJson =>

    val freeBytes = (utilizationJson \ "freeBytes").asOpt[Long]
    val sizeBytes = (utilizationJson \ "sizeBytes").asOpt[Long]
    val usedBytes = (utilizationJson \ "usedBytes").asOpt[Long]

    DataStoreUtilization(freeBytes, sizeBytes, usedBytes)
  }
 }

private def getDataStoreLuns(dataStoreJson: JsValue): Option[List[DataStoreLuns]] = {

(dataStoreJson \ "luns").asOpt[List[JsObject]].map { luns =>
  luns map {
    lunJson =>
      val model = (lunJson \ "model").asOpt[String]
      val canonicalName = (lunJson \ "CanonicalName").asOpt[String]
      val vendor = (lunJson \ "vendor").asOpt[String]

      DataStoreLuns(model, canonicalName, vendor)
  }
 }
}
}
```

I am getting following error:

```
play - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't serialize class ....models.DataStoreUtilization
```

How to resolve this error??